# I want to make alert on my Custom map pin taped like as screen shot

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mkmapview

[image]How can I make these type alert using custom code like as default MKMapview. You can see it in Screen shot

Comment: that call out or u want any alert if u add pin and select on that  u will be get a call out ...what u want to do exactly..?

Comment: I added custom pin on map . but I wanna same alert as Current Location  . You can see in capture. How is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [TapKu Alerts with Images for iOS](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/tapku-alerts-with-images)

Also you can find different type of custom UIAlertViews [here](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=alert)

Comment: But I need same as current location.....